# How to use left function in subquery using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this :

```
select * from employee where (employee_id in (SELECT DISTINCT 
SubTable.blockid 
        FROM 
                  broad.territory_block 
                  BlockSubTable 
                                         WHERE  ( ( 
                  BlockSubTable.id IN ( 398 ) ))))
```

Now here my `employee_id` is of 10 digits and the output of the subquery would be of 13 digits. I tried using `left('',10)` for matching the subquery output but getting error for `misplaced left function`. Can someone please help me how should I use `left` function to match the result. I need to match the `employee_id` with the subquery output

P.S : This is not the actual query, created for explaining the problem

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I'm totally lost why you wold compare something called `employeeid` to something called `blockid`.

Comment: What are the data types of those columns?

Comment: did u tried SELECT DISTINCT  LEFT(SubTable.blockid , 10) FROM ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply it to the column:

```
select * 
from employee 
where employee_id in (SELECT left(blockid, 13)
                      FROM  BlockSubTable 
                      WHERE  BlockSubTable.id IN ( 398 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help.!! :D

Comment: @Developer52 you should accept the answer if it resolves your problem